# How do I, as the platform, retrieve the exchange rate for a connected out that was direct charged?

Tags: stripe-payments

Through the Stripe API, I am wondering if I can retrieve the exchange rate for connected accounts as the platform on direct charges made on the connected account? Here is my scenario:

The platform operates in USD but the connected account is in CAD. When a direct charge is made in the connected account, can I retrieve  as the platform the USD to CAD exchange rate that was used for the specific transaction a few days/week later?

Thank you for your help! I'm not sure if it's possible

Comment: When creating a Direct Charge, it is converted to the Connected Account’s default currency while the application fees are converted to the Platform’s default currency [1] You want to retrieve the funds collected by the Connected Accounts in the Platform Currency?


[1] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/currencies#direct-charges

Comment: I am not looking to retrieve the funds but rather just retrieve the exchange rate that was used on the connected account's direct charge. Can I do that in the API as the platform?

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, hopefully this helps.

> can I retrieve  as the platform the USD to CAD exchange rate that was used for the specific transaction a few days/week later?

You can get this as soon as the payment is succeeded.

This is the flow:
Payment Intent > Charge > Balance Transaction
The exchange rate lives on the Balance Transaction

Depending on the object you start from, you can get the Balance Transaction (and the `exchange_rate`) with this code (in py here):

```
stripe.Charge.retrieve(
  ch_id, # charge id
  stripe_account=acct_id # connected account id
  expand=['balance_transaction'] # will include the Balance Transaction object
)
```

Or this code:

```
stripe.PaymentIntent.retrieve(
  pi_id, # Payment Intent id
  stripe_account=acct_id # connected account id
  expand=['latest_charge.balance_transaction'] # will include the Balance Transaction object (only works with API version ^2022-11-15)
)
```